# Concern module not available in model despite being included (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch

I'm migrating my app from solr to Elasticsearch for document searching. The recommended pattern for deploying Elasticsearch is to include the Elasticsearch functionality (ie `Elasticsearch::Model` and `Elasticsearch::Model::Indexing`) in a Rails concern and then include this module in your model. I've implemented this as such. (Some methods temporarily commented out as I'm working through this.)

```
#app/models/concerns/elasticsearch_user.rb
require 'active_support/concern'

module ElasticsearchUser

extend ActiveSupport::Concern

included do
  require 'elasticsearch/model'
  include Elasticsearch::Model
  include Elasticsearch::Model::Indexing

  #mapping do
  #  #to-do
  #end

  #def self.search(query)
  #  _elasticsearch_.search(
  #    {
  #        query: {
  #         multi_match: {
  #             query: query,
  #             fields: ['username^2', 'email', 'full_name']
  #         }
  #        }
  #    }
  #  )
  #end

  end
end


#User.rb
...
# Elasticsearch configuration
include ElasticsearchUser
# index_name "users" <-- This value is inferred automatically by the model name
settings index: { number_of_shards: 1 } do
  mappings dynamic: 'false' do
    indexes :username
    indexes :email
    indexes :full_name
  end
end
...
def as_indexed_json(options={})
  self.as_json(only: [:username, :email, :full_name],
               methods: [:full_name]
  )
end
```

I can call `Model.import` and `Model.search` with no problems. Calling things like `Model._elasticsearch_.create_index!` (with and without the `_elasticsearch_` namespace) throw a NoMethodError. I've tried including `Elasticsearch::Model` directly in my model definition with no success. I've also tried requiring `active_support/concern' at the top of my model - no luck there either. It seems obvious that the module/concern is not being included in my model but I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually wound up having nothing to do with including the concern. I added some logging (`we made it to the search`) to my search method and found this in the console output. With some help from the Elasticsearch folk, we realized I was using `_elasticsearch_`, but it's `__elasticsearch__` with two underscores. Of all the things...

Answer (score 0):

Are you using correct rails version
Try!! In console

```
require 'active_support/concern'
```

If it returns nil module is not being imported

Comment: It does return `false` when I call this from the console.

Comment: Then you may not be using proper rails version